# BSC chunking log files

Tags: bsc, logs

I have a BSC full node running and I have bsc logs being created on /bsc/logs/bsc.log.

What's bothering me is that it's chunking the log files in too small pieces of around 350K each, see output below for example:

```
344K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_00
344K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_01
340K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_02
344K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_03
348K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_04
344K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_05
348K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_06
332K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_07
348K    /bsc/logs/bsc.log.2021-08-15_08
```

I have the following parameters set in config.toml:

```
[Node.LogConfig]
FilePath = "logs/bsc.log"
MaxBytesSize = 10485760
Level = "info"
FileRoot = ""
```

As you can see above it's defined to have a max size of 10Mb.

My configs:

```
Geth
Version: 1.1.0
Git Commit: 7822e9e2a1c11e5e9f989b740ba0166a9cd96db1
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.16.7
Operating System: linux
```

O.S: Ubuntu 20.04

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the log files grow till 10Mb to then create a new file?